# Instagram API: Please supply a valid action from the following

Tags: javascript, instagram

I am currently using the node api nodegram, and I'm trying to follow a user. Here is my code:

```
gram.post('users/'+userlist[0]+'/relationship', {action:'follow'}).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
```

It returns this error:

> This action is invalid. Please supply a valid action from the following: follow, unfollow, approve, ignore, block, unblock

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed "/" before users, your URL should be like this.

> gram.post('/users/'+userlist[0]+'/relationship',
>   {action:'follow'}).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man, but it seems the api was not sending the data as post data, but as a parameter, so a few code patches here and there solved it. :)